# Flash HTML text not showing

Tags: html, actionscript, fonts, embed

I'm trying to display HTML text in a text field on the stage, but the text formatting doesn't show.
I am embedding all font variations in the library (arial bold and arial regular) and I even have dynamic text fields on the stage that embed arial bold and arial regular.

Still, this code does not display bold text:

```
myField.htmlText = "Regular and <b>bold</b>";
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Odd. Maybe your text field is already bold by some other setting outside the field?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Flash that causes HTML bold text to not display. Sometimes, opening the text field and adding one regular letter, and one bold letter, fixes it - although it depends on the font. Hope that saves some people a headache!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AS2, you have to specify: myField.html=true in order to allow HTML.

Answer (score 1):

@dome answered correct:

In **Character** panel you need to find **Anti-alias**, and chose "**Use device fonts**"
Then export your flash and HTML edited text should appear.

Answer (score 0):

it's a font problem. Try to select a system font, like "_sans" or "_serif".

EDIT: in anti-alias select "Use device fonts". This should work with Arial and any other font that is installed in the user machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another html tag such as `<i></i>` or `<a href=""></a>`? Sometimes other  settings may alter the behavior of your textfield. Have you already tried your textfield inside a new .fla file?

Comment: I've tried every possible combination! Even with empty FLA files containing nothing but those few text fields and fonts.
The one thing that DOES work is when I export the exact same code from CS3! So the code is OK and the problem is with CS4?

Comment: Hey Ted! Could you post somewhere your misbehaving fla file? Have you already moved the fonts as mentioned by dome?